# How do I enable a forced stop & disabled Bluetooth Share app on Android 4.0.4 (Ice Cream Sandwich)

Tags: applications, 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, bluetooth

Over enthusiastic to disable many distracting apps on my Sony Xperia U (ST25i) I went "settings>apps>all" and disabled away.  Where no disable option was available, I clicked on force stop.  With Bluetooth Share I stupidly took it to be a social networking app and disabled it, later force stopping it.  Dumb, I know, but how do I get it back?  I'm fairly new to all of this, obviously, so please be very specific in responding.  Many thanks.

Comment: Click the "Enable" button that is located at the same point where you clicked "Disable"?

Comment: Thanks Robert, but clicking "Disable" and "Force stop" buttons extinguished their lights and made both inoperable. "Disable" did not change to "Enable". Clicking a button with an extinguished light does nothing, of course. But installing Syncios Manager to allow my Xperia and PC to talk has, at least, brought the "Force stop" button light back on again. The "Disable" button, however, remains dead.

Answer (score 0):

For apps that are forced stopped, locate them in the Play Store and click Enable button to enable them.

Comment: I think you mean *For apps that are disabled* and not *forced stopped*.